# Cant get the syntax correct for a practice template

Tags: javascript, cordova

I hope this isn't too much code to look through to correct what I think may be a few syntax errors. I am getting lots of different types of errors as I have gone through and tried to get this code to compile but the most recent is 
"Critical error was detected at line 33, column 5 in ms-appx://io.cordova.myapp7523d86d4f8a4241bd8c3bad3d5fe0a3/www/scripts/index.js. SCRIPT1006: Expected ')", which is the "setPlaceholderImage()" line.

This is a practice template app that can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879349.aspx TITLED:Cross-Platform : Write Cross-Platform Hybrid Apps in Visual Studio with Apache Cordova.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind(this),         false);

    function onDeviceReady() {

        // Perform other initialization here.
    };
    locate();
    document.getElementById("btnLocate").addEventListener("click", locate);

    (function locate() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            App.lastPosition = {
                latitude: position.coords.latitude, 
                longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                address: "(  position.coords.latitude  )" + "(  position.coords.longitude  )" };

            // Go translate the coordinates into an address using the Bing Map Web API.
            updatePosition();
        }, function (error) {
            WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Unable to get location: "
             + error.message, "app");
        }, {
            maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true
        });
    }

    setPlaceholderImage(){
document.getElementById("photo").addEventListener("click",   capturePhoto.bind(photo));
}
function capturePhoto() {
    var photoDiv = this;
    // Capture camera image into a file.
    navigator.camera.getPicture(cameraSuccess, cameraError) {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URL,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
        allotEdits: true
        correctOrientation: true
    });
    function cameraSuccess(imageFile) {
        // Save for share and enable Share button.
        App.lastCapture = imageFile;
        document.getElementById("btnShare").disabled = false;
        // Do letterboxing and assign to img.src.
        scaleImageToFit(photoDiv.querySelector("img"), 
          photoDiv, App.lastCapture);
    };
    function cameraError(error) {
        WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Unable to obtain picture: " + error, "app");
    };
}

document.getElementById("btnShare").addEventListener("click", App.share);
function share() {
    var txtLocation = document.getElementById("txtLocation").value;
    plugins.socialsharing.share("At " + txtLocation, "Here My Am!",
      App.lastCapture);
}

} )();
```

Comment: document.addEventListener(event, function, useCapture) 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp

Comment: there are many errors in that code, extra `}` in one place, not enough `(` in others ... I'd be looking at using something like jshint/jslint to fix that mess up

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm just realizing that i have such a long way to go